# Llamar la ultima coordenada con geocoder en android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, gps, google-geocoding-api

Estoy obteniendo mi localización en donde se requiere wifi datos móviles o gps para obtenerla, sucede que el proyecto es para ejecutarse en una via rural donde se tienen siempre datos móviles pero en algunas zonas se pierde temporalmente la señal de red, creo que podría utilizar la ultima de las coordenadas que se recibió en ese momento donde no hay red pero no se como podría obtenerla, agregare los métodos donde obtengo las coordenadas y las convierto en dirección para contextualizar:

```
 private void localizacion() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        }, 1);
    }
    ubicacion = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location loc = ubicacion.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

}
//Metodo que actualiza ubicacion en tiempo real
private void registrarLocalizacion() {
    ubicacion = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    ubicacion.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 0, new milocalizacionListener());
}
//Metodo para volver a la actividad anterior
public void devolverMenu(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

//Convertidor Geocoder para obtener direccion precisa
private class milocalizacionListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //System.out.println("La direccion ha cambiado");
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> direccion = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
            //System.out.println(direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0));

            tDireccion.setText(direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


    }
}
```

}

Actvity donde obtengo coordenadas y direccion:

```
LocationManager locationManager;
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
AlertDialog alert = null;

public static final String PREFERENCIAS = "MyPrefs";
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registros);

    //getDatos(Locale.getDefault());

    ////////////////Persistencia sin conexion FireStore///////////////////////////
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
            .build();
    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ParoImpar();

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    registrarLocalizacion();
    localizacion();
    detectarConx();
}//FinOnCreate

private void detectarConx() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean hayConexion = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();

    if (hayConexion) {

    } else {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences((getString(R.string.preference_file_key)),MODE_PRIVATE);
        String direc = prefs.getString((getString(R.string.preference_file_key)),"");
        tDireccion.setText(direc);
    }

}

public void ConvertidordeCoordenadas() {

    GPStracker g = new GPStracker(getApplicationContext());


    Location l = g.getLocation();
    if (l != null) {
        double lat = l.getLatitude();
        double lon = l.getLongitude();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> direccion = geocoder.getFromLocation(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude(), 1);
            //System.out.println(direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0));

            //tDireccion.setText(direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sin GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

//Metodo para detectar id par o impar
public void ParoImpar() {
    if (count.get() % 2 == 0) {
        //Log.d("ParoImpar","= Par");
    } else {
        //Log.d("ParoImpar","= Impar");
    }

}

//Metodo para detectar gps activo
public void AlertNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("El GPS se encuentra apagado, ¿Desea activarlo?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

//Metodo que obtiene fecha y hora
public void times(View v) {
}

//Metodo que obtiene ubicacion
private void localizacion() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        }, 1);
    }
    ubicacion = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location loc = ubicacion.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

}

//Metodo que actualiza ubicacion en tiempo real
private void registrarLocalizacion() {
    ubicacion = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    ubicacion.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 0, new milocalizacionListener());
}

//Metodo para volver a la actividad anterior
public void devolverMenu(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

//Convertidor Geocoder para obtener direccion precisa
private class milocalizacionListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //System.out.println("La direccion ha cambiado");
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> direccion = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            //System.out.println(direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0));

            tDireccion.setText(direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0));

            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(getString(R.string.direccion_key), tDireccion.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberias hacer en este caso es guardar siempre la ultima coordenada en [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) (que seria sobreescribir la que se solicita cuando hay conexion) , entonces, cada vez que solicites `geocoder.getFromLocation` chequea primero si hay conexion, si no hay usa la misma linea pero con la latitud y longitud del sharedpreferences, que deberia ser la ultima.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta creo que puede ser la mejor manera de solucionarlo pero aun no logro conseguirlo agregue a mi publicacion tal vez me puedes indicar alguna recomendacion

Comment: Chequea esta pagina : https://expocodetech.com/como-usar-sharedpreferences-en-android/ , la idea de usar sharedpreferences es que por cada coordenada que encuentras la guardes ahi, entonces se va sobreescribiendo y cuando no logre buscar, esa va a ser la ultima, y con eso solo usas esos dos valores para tu geocoder, igualmente, recorda que el geocoder encuentra su informacion desde internet.

Comment: usa .apply en cambio de .commit en tu sharedpreferences

Comment: Como ahi vi , en esta linea       `editor.putString(getString(R.string.direccion_key), tDireccion.getText().toString());`, esta bien que guardes la direccion , pero asegurate que al menos haya internet para guardar la primera vez

Comment: Gracia ahora me va funcionando muy bien!!